# How to Control Multiple threads of Same Object?

Tags: java, android

following is inside my button click in android

```
protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          public void onClick(View arg0)
                   {
                       if(connectThread!=null)
                            {
                               connectThread.kill();
                            }
                        connectThread=new ConnectThread(device);
                        connectThread.start();
                   }
}
```

I have made a `boolean` volatile variable running in `ConnectThread` class which is true by default and kill method will set it value to false.
Problem is that still it is not working the reason may be that in my `ConnectThread` run method im creating another thread but that should not be the problem since that gets called from the run method and since that will be child thread of `ConnectThread`; on killing connectThread that will automatically get cancelled?

kill method of `ConnectThread`

```
   public void kill()
               {
                 running=false;
               }
```

run method of `ConnectThread`

```
 public void run()
         {
              while(running)
                       {
                       }
         }
```

Comment: I figured it out myself on connected event i called kill method to have it stopped and on click method i have to set it true by making another method in thread that will set running to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app was still active on your device, and you started a second connection thread, the bluetooth device might not be available.

I recommend you read up on the [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Comment: Is there a way that on the second button clicked previous thread get demolished and new thread starts communicating

Comment: ALifeCycle comes into play when i pause the application by going back or forwarding or a dialog box appears but the problem is that i remain on the current activity and click button multiple times to send same data.